# Traffic monitoring with Tor

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration

Is there a downloadable application that will put a Tor node traffic monitor visual on my screen? Even just a go/no go activity level? I am still on about how much access and/or control the exit node owner can potentially have considering that I understand that the whole raison d'etre for Tor is complete (or as complete as possible) privacy for the user.

Answer (score 2):

You can start with [Arm](https://www.torproject.org/projects/arm.html.en) and here [Arm project site](https://www.atagar.com/arm/)